# Call Handle Time and Call Volume Relation

Tags: excel, formula, volume

I've got a conundrum. It's hole in my knowledge thus I know there's something I'm missing.

I have Call Handle Times for 3 call types. I want to know how impacting a given call type is on the total. However, I just can't figure out WHAT I'm trying to figure out. Let me provide an example

[image]

```
|             |       Handle Time         |
|-------------|-------------|------|------|
| Call Type 1 |          50 |   40 |   44 |
| Call Type 2 |         500 |  506 |  687 |
| Call Type 3 |        1193 | 1253 | 1432 |
|             |                           |
|             |        Volume             |
| Call Type 1 |        2052 | 2024 | 1822 |
| Call Type 2 |        2122 | 2020 | 1821 |
| Call Type 3 |        3112 | 2820 | 2516 |
| Total       |        7276 | 6864 | 6159 |
```

I know there must be some formulated way to calculate this relation of these two metrics, but for the life of me I can't even see what that should be. It's on the tip of my tongue but keeps eluding me. Any help would be dearly appreciated.

VR
Talley

Comment: Not sure what you're looking for in terms of "impacting call types". Percentage of handle time to the total? Ratio of handle time to volume?

Comment: I think so? So that's the problem mainly, I'm not certain how to say what I want to see. So in the sample the call type 1 is low HT and moderate volume. This means to me it has less impact. Call type 2 has a high HT but about the same volume, obviously this means it impacts more. However, if for example Call Type 1 had a much high HT and lower volume, then it would still be minorly impactful to the whole since it has a low volume. I just... I don't know how to display that. I feel like it can be of course, but I'm just not seeing how to formulate it.